# Multi value parameter in SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services

How can you tell what value was selected first in a multi value parameter in SSRS 2008?

Example
a,b,c 
are the values

and I would like to know if b was selected first and if so change the string to be b,a,c

Comment: Heya, welcome to SO! Please have a look at the FAQ or [this checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/162730) on creating questions. Note that you can edit your question at any time to improve it!

Comment: As a start to improving your question, let us know what you mean by "selected first." Does this mean it came from a dataset first, the user clicked on this value first, or that the user used this in a previous report execution?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean tracking which value a user clicked on first in the web interface, then you can't get this functionality through SSRS. A multi-value parameter doesn't preserve this order.

A few workarounds come to mind:

**Create multiple parameters**

Create multiple parameters such as "Primary BU" and "Secondary BUs." You could even remove items selected as primary from the secondary list.

**Create your own interface**

You can always create your own "Report Manager" interface and then call reports and serve them yourself. You get complete flexibility over the UI, but still get SSRS to handle data, report creation, and export formats.

**Javascript hacking**

The SSRS webpage is a webpage after all. In theory, you can insert your own code. I wouldn't recommend this, as updates may break your code though.